# Does "Concurrent Insert" improve Database INSERTION speed?

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, tokudb

I need to insert very large amount of data(over 1 billion rows) to one table.

I used TokuDB as my Database Engine. And I know it supports "Concurrent Insert".

I'm just wondering if I have a very powerful server to host my DB. Does the "Concurrent Insert" improve Insertion speed?

Comment: Are you bulk loading this table (using something like "load data infile ...") or inserting via insert statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean concurrent inserts like described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html then no, it doesn't make your inserts any faster. It simply means you can still read the table while the inserts take place.

This feature is only relevant for engines that use table-level locking.